# Setting TIFF tags to new values results, doesnt quite set the tags to the new values and results in odd behavior

Tags: c#, .net, compression, tiff, libtiff

```
        using (Tiff input = Tiff.Open(@"new.tif", "r"))
        {
            if (input == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Could not open incoming image");
                return;
            }

            if (input.IsTiled())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Could not process tiled image");
                return;
            }

            using (Tiff output = Tiff.Open("newnew.tif", "w"))
            {
                int numberOfDirectories = input.NumberOfDirectories();
                int rps = 3500;
                for (short i = 0; i < numberOfDirectories; ++i)
                {
                    input.SetDirectory(i);
                    copyTags(input, output);
                    copyStrips(input, output);
                    output.SetField(TiffTag.ROWSPERSTRIP,rps);
                    output.WriteDirectory();
                }
                output.Close();
            }

        }
```

When I debug the value of output after "output.SetField(TiffTag.ROWSPERSTRIP,rps)" step, the ROWSPERSTRIP tag value is still the old one and not set to the new one

When I debug the value of output after "output.WriteDirectory()" step, the ROWSPERSTRIP tag value is suddenly set to -1

Can anyone please explain this strange behavior??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `copyTags(input, output);`and `copyStrips(input, output)`do what their names imply they write to the output stream, right?

However accoding to the [docs](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/help/well-known-tags-and-their-value%28s%29-data-types.aspx) there are some, actually **quite** some fields, you can't set after having started to write.

Quote:

> TiffTag.ROWSPERSTRIP  -  Tag may not have its values changed once data is written to file/stream.

So I guess all those tag fields must be set first.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right. setting the field after copytags and before copystrips is setting the tagvalue to the new value.However, write directory function is setting the tag value to -1